# Force 10 packet capture

Tags: force10

Is there a way to make libpcap compatible packet captures using Dell Force 10 switches? Or at least a way to show real time packet activity that will display something similar to the console output of tcpdump or snoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force10 routers and switches have a top level `tcpdump` command that can create libpcap compatible captures.

Comment: Unfortunately for many (high speed especially) dell switches there is no way to specify an interface other than the management network to capture from.